# Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Android Studio cannot connect to the mobile calendar

Tags: android

I don't know how to solve it. Please help me in solving this issue. Is the format of DateTime correct? Please help, thanks so much, much of appreciation. I have tried to solve it but doesn't work.

```
     addToCalendar(getApplicationContext(), "hello","2012/10/10 10:05:33" );
    }


        public static void addToCalendar(Context oContext, final String title, final String eventStartDate)
        {
            String eventUriString = null;

            long startDate = new Date(eventStartDate).getTime();
            long endDate = new Date(eventStartDate).getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60; // For next 1hr
            TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

            ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 1 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 20)
            {
                eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";

                eventValues.put("calendar_id", 1);
                eventValues.put("title", title);
                eventValues.put("description", "");
                eventValues.put("eventLocation", "");

                eventValues.put("dtstart", startDate);
                eventValues.put("dtend", endDate);

                eventValues.put("eventStatus", "");
                eventValues.put("visibility", 3);
                eventValues.put("transparency", 0);
                eventValues.put("hasAlarm", 1);

                Uri eventUri = oContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString), eventValues);
                long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());

                String reminderUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/reminders";

                ContentValues reminderValues = new ContentValues();

                reminderValues.put("event_id", eventID);
                reminderValues.put("minutes", 5);
                reminderValues.put("method", 1);

                oContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(reminderUriString), reminderValues);

            }
            else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 )
            {
                eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startDate);
                eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endDate);
                eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
                eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "");
                eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 3);
                eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());

                oContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, eventValues);
            }

            Toast.makeText(oContext, "Event Created on : " + startDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

error log

```
04-10 13:41:50.861  14823-14823/com.example.lean.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.lean.myapplication, PID: 14823
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lean.myapplication/com.example.lean.myapplication.MyActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Event values must include an eventTimezone
        at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2276)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1221)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5094)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Event values must include an eventTimezone
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:468)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1190)
        at com.example.lean.myapplication.MyActivity.addToCalendar(MyActivity.java:66)
        at com.example.lean.myapplication.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5249)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1096)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2190)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error *tells* you what is wrong: "Event values must include an eventTimezone"

Just add the following to your `ContentValues` variable:

`eventValues.put("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getID());`

Comment: i think the directory to my mobile calendar is wrong. do u have any idea how can i figure it out

Comment: the program runs with no error. however, the calendar of my phone doesn't respond.

Comment: Use a background thread to handle any calculations and update the UI using `runOnUiThread()` - see [this](https://vaibhavtolia.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/79/)